# issue accessing array value in associative array

Tags: php, json

Here is the result of `var_dump($my_var["id"])` on the object I'm having issues with:

```
array(1) { ["$t"]=> string(38) "tag:youtube.com,2008:video:PFtBzEqYOhc" }
```

I want to access the `string(38)` part of that associative array, but when I type:

```
echo $my_var["id"]["$t"]
```

I get nothing. What's the problem?

Comment: You should consider this as bad practice, this is not a speaking key name. Choose some different name, without dollars and you wouldn't have any trouble with it

Comment: someone tell the youtube guys, as this is their API i'm handling

Comment: google sucks more everyday :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In double quotes, dollar signs start variable references. Use single quotes:

```
echo $my_var['id']['$t'];
```

For more information, refer to the [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).